# Is it possible to use OWASP ESAPI in J2SE for encodeForURL?

Tags: java, owasp

How to use OWASP ESAPI in J2SE? When I import the jar to my project. and use the method

```
      ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL(string url)
```

,it throws an Exception Caused by:

```
       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
```

But my program don't need Servlet. So as the title, how to use ESAPI in J2SE? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The ESAPI locator class has dependencies on the JavaEE HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest classes so you can't use it the way that you did. However, you could use:

```
import org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder;
...
DefaultEncoder.getInstance().encodeForURL(url_string);
```

and get the same effect. It's ugly, yes, but should work as long as you don't use anything else that requires any JavaEE classes.

Comment: nope - warning about unhandled exception using that method